# Firebase Storage: User does not have permission to access 'path'

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-storage, angularfire2

I'm trying to upload files to firebase storage with angularfire2.

that's my code :

```
 public pushUploadAudio(upload: AudioFile){

   let id = this.afs.createId();
   let storageRef = firebase.storage().ref();
  //  the audio file will be uploaded to the id generated to the Podcast Document
   let uploadTask = storageRef.child(`audio_files/${id}`).put(upload.file);
   uploadTask.on(firebase.storage.TaskEvent.STATE_CHANGED,
    (snapshot) =>{
      // upload in progress
      upload.progress = Math.floor((uploadTask.snapshot.bytesTransferred / uploadTask.snapshot.totalBytes )* 100)
    },
    (error) =>{
      // upload failed
      this.flashMessagesService.show('Oh snap! please try again..',  { cssClass: 'alert alert-danger', timeout: 1500 })      
      console.log(error)
    },
    () => {
      // upload success
      upload.url = uploadTask.snapshot.downloadURL;
          //  upload.name is the name ref in firebase storage
      upload.name = uploadTask.snapshot.ref.name;
      upload.podcast_id = id;
      this.flashMessagesService.show('File was successfuly uploaded!',  { cssClass: 'alert alert-success', timeout: 1500 })

    }
  )
 }
```

storage rules :

```
service firebase.storage {
  match /image_files {
    match /{allPaths=**} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth != null;
    }
  }
}
```

and i'm getting the following error :

```
FirebaseStorageError {code_: "storage/unauthorized", message_: "Firebase Storage: User does not have permission to access 'audio_files/WKkEKp4o5BUYOt5J4vsX'.", serverResponse_: "{↵  "error": {↵    "code": 403,↵    "message": "Pe…n denied. Could not perform this operation"↵  }↵}", name_: "FirebaseError"}
```

if i make the storage rules to be `allow read, write: if true = true;`
then it does upload .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure the user is logged in, because if `auth` is false, the write will denied, as per your rules. For example, from the [Firebase documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/anonymous-auth):

```
firebase.auth().signInAnonymously().catch(function(error) {
  // Handle Errors here.
  var errorCode = error.code;
  var errorMessage = error.message;
  // ...
});
```

Comment: im using googleLogin.
    `googleLogin() {
     const provider = new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider();
    return this.oAuthLogin(provider);
    }
    private oAuthLogin(provider){
     return this.afAuth.auth.signInWithPopup(provider)
     .then((credential)=> {
       this.updateUserData(credential)
       this.router.navigate(['/home'])
     })
   }`